# change the paper size on a label size in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, printing

How can I change the paper size on a label printer by javascript and css. I searched a lot but I couldn't find a solution for it.

```
<section class="label-content">
    <section>
        <div class="item-section Buyer">
            <div class="item"><span class="question">name :</span><span class="space">sara</span></div>
            <div class="item"><span class="question">age :</span><span>22</span></div>
            <div class="item"><span class="question">phone :</span><span>12344555555</span></div>
            <div class="item"><span class="question">email :</span><span>sara@gmail.com</span></div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <button class="print" onclick="print_page(this)">print </button>
</section>

 function print_page(element) {
        window.print();
    }
```

Comment: There's sseveral SO answers out there - and many from other sources. Not sure what you searched for but "can javascript change printer paper size?" gave quite a lot of info. Basically, No. But you can of course set the right sizes up in terms of the layout.

Comment: Thanks @A Haworth,I try something like this :   ` .label-content {
            page-break-after: always;
        }` or this one   ` @page {
  size: 4in 6in;
}` but the size of paper didn't  change just the size of content will be changed